# How to modularize templates in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

## base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

## head.html

```
<title>Example</title>
```

## body.html

```
<h1>Example Django</h1>
```

Using django, you can render the template "base.html" but replace the blocks "head" and "body", respectively, by templates "head.html" and "body.html"?

Comment: so whats your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand you right, you need `include` tag
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% include "head.html" %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% include "body.html" %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

{% include "base.html" %}

```
{% block head %}
 {% include "head.html" %}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
 {% include "body.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```